# How Odoo Stores Session?

Tags: session, odoo

How Odoo store the login session when user logged in.
I have searched many link but didn't get any satisfied answer. 
can anyone explain session in odoo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Session in odoo v8 is stored in **file system**. the path of the session is in the default data directory. it can be

```
Mac OS X: ~/Library/Application Support/odoo
Unix: ~/.local/share/odoo  
Win XP: C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\<AppAuthor>\odoo
Win 7: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\<AppAuthor>\odoo
windows 10: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\OpenERP S.A\Odoo\sessions
```

For Unix, Odoo follows the XDG spec and supports $XDG_DATA_HOME.
That means, by default `~/.local/share/Odoo`

Comment: I found the question in 2021 and I want to update the answer for those who come here later  .Session in Odoo v13.
`windows 10: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\OpenERP S.A\Odoo\sessions`

Answer (score 7):

In your openerp-server-conf you can define the custom file storage path using the attribute

```
data_dir = 'Your custom path'
```

If you need to access the odoo session in your codes, just try following possibilities

in python script:

```
 session = env['ir.sessions']

 or
 session = request.session
 or
 you can get session info from the route '/web/session/get_session_info'
 ie, 
@http.route('/web/session/get_session_info',type='json',auth="none")
def get_session_info(self):
    request.uid = request.session.uid
    request.disable_db = False
    return self.session_info()
```

In js

```
try to Implement operations on 
var session = require('web.session'); this session object
```

Cheers !